# SQL Server : count items in different columns and group them

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Looked through a few posts and haven't found an workable answer to this yet.

Example of a table I have:

```
Item 1     | Item 2    | Item 3 |  Item 4 |
-----------------------------------------------------
Hamburger    Fries       Soda      Salad
Fries        Hamburger   Soda
Salad        Soda        Soda
Hamburger    Fries
```

Then I'm trying to count and group them so they show up like this.

```
4 Soda
3 Hamburger
3 Fries
2 Salad
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Unpivot` the data and do the count

```
select Items,count(1)
from yourtable
cross apply(values (Item1),(Item2),(Item3),(Item4)) CA (items)
Group by Items
```

Comment: beat me to it. +1

Comment: Side question: So say like Soda, Hamburger, Fries, Salad, were actually codes, and I am trying to join another table, that would display there actual names for the end user.    Like another table has Hamburger | real name, and then for the sql i was joining the tables on OtherTable.Code = YourTable.Item1, so it would display what the end user usually picks.

Comment: @mol - Make it as new question. Most importantly try something before posting the question

Comment: ah figured it out, i just had to join the table on say Items with the other table.